# I want to select only positive values from SQL data

Tags: sql

I want to select only positive values from SQL data.

Example :

```
Select A, (10-A) as B   
From Table1 where B >= 0
```

Result will be:

[image]

but I want the result with only positive values, like

[image]

I tried but I am not getting a proper result.

Please if anyone can help me, it would be of a great help.

Thank you
Nag

Comment: why not use filter on column B? ```Select A, B from Table1 where B > 0```

Comment: Have you figured this out, what have you done wrong? Should we start closing this question since you seem abandoned it?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select A, B
FROM
    (Select A, (10-A) as B From Table1) t
WHERE t.B > 0
```

You can just go direct

```sql
select A, (10-A) as B
FROM
    Table1
WHERE (10 - A) > 0
```

The difference would be important - if you need `ORDER BY`

Fiddle

```sql
create table table1 (a int);
insert into table1 values (1);
insert into table1 values (2);
insert into table1 values (3);
insert into table1 values (4);
insert into table1 values (20);
insert into table1 values (30);
insert into table1 values (40);
```

result

> A  B
> 1   9
> 2   8
> 3   7
> 4   6

Comment: Hi T.S,  I tried but i am getting both values - and + , but i want only positive values from the condition.

Comment: @nagendrag no. It is working. see ^^^^

Comment: @nagendrag Ok, second statement war incorrect - I fixed it

Comment: i tried but ,its showing invalid column name for B, because there's  no column B in the table, my question is from the condition we are using i should get only positive values

Comment: @nagendrag you have not posted the type of DB engine you're using. I've build a fiddle and this is working. It would work in the ANSI SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A, (10-A)>=0 as B   
From Table1
```

Comment: i tried even if the result is negative  (-7) it is showing 7

Comment: check again ...